# When creating symbolic links on ubuntu I sometimes get an odd result

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, symlink

I'm trying to create a bunch of symbolic links for all the files in a directory. It seems like, when I type this command in the shell manually, it works just fine, but when I run it in a shell script, or even use the up arrow to re-run it, I get the following problem.

```
$ sudo ln -s /path/to/my/files/* /the/target/directory/
```

This should create a bunch of sym links in /path/to/my/files and if I type the command in manuall, it indeed does, however, when I run the command from a shell script, or use the up arrow to re-run it I get a single symbolic link in /the/target/directory/ called * as in the link name is actually '*' and I then have to run

```
$ sudo rm *
```

To delete it, which just seems insane to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you run that command in the script, are there any files in `/path/to/my/files`? If not, then by default the wildcard has nothing to expand to, and it is not replaced. You end up with the literal "*". You might want to check out `shopt -s nullglob` and run the `ln` command like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
sudo ln -s -t /the/target/directory /path/to/my/files/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script uses `sh` and your using `bash` when executing the command.

You may try something like this:

`for file in $(ls /path/to/my/files/*) do
     ln -s "${file}" "/the/target/directory/"${file}"
   done`